# How to set a path for opening the pdf file stored in iBooks in iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I write the code to open the pdf file located

```
  NSArray  *paths =    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *pdfFilePath =[documentsDir  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"421_core_animation_essentials.pdf"];
        fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:pdfFilePath];
        QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
        previewController.dataSource = self;
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:previewController animated:YES];
        [previewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil];
        [previewController release];
```

It is working while testing in simulator but when testing in iPad device it doesn't work.
please help me.

Comment: For apply formatting for coding just select whole code and press control + k for pc and for mac command + k :)

Answer (score 0):

iOS device file systems are case-sensitive unlike the simulator which isn't.

Therefore check the filename for case sensitivity on:

```
NSString *pdfFilePath =[documentsDir  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"421_core_animation_essentials.pdf"];
```